# Rails - wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) for a newly generated Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just setup a new rails app, and I uses `rails generate controller Pages` to create a blank page controller, then I added empty methods and views. I changed the route.rb to redirect to `pages/:action`, so it should display `foo.html.erb` for `pages/foo`. However, I have this error everytime I'm trying to access any of the page (`pages/`, `pages/index`, `pages/course`, etc.)

**localhost:3000/pages/register** (note: the actual `Rails.root` is different)

```
ArgumentError in PagesController#register
wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Rails.root: C:/railsapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `initialize'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/url_for.rb:25:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:179:in `action_method?'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:230:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:17:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:130:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__664391637__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip,deflate,sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
Response

Headers:

None
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def course
  end

  def course_info
  end

  def register
  end

  def nav
  end
end
```

**route.rb**

```
ChulaLounge::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'pages#nav'
  get '/pages/:action', :controller => 'pages'

end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=mybook_rails_4_0
gem 'rails'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'pg'
end

  gem 'haml'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'designmodo-flatuipro-rails', '1.1.3.1'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'angularjs-rails'

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate your error with the same style of routes and it worked fine. The only thing I can think of is maybe register is a super method in your class hierarchy and you've over-ridden it?

Comment: This is a newly created rails app, so I didnt make any changes to the newly generated content other than what I have shown above.

Comment: Ok I've created a new rails 4 app, with ruby 1.9.3-p448 and copy pasted everything you did here. I had to create a view, but after that it all worked ok. I'd say there's a problem with your specific setup. I've never developed with rails on windows so I can't help much with that. But I'd suggest that developing on windows is taking the hard route, because it's less common and there may be many things that don't work properly. If I were you I'd try dual-booting a linux distro for development.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using rails 4. Is that the case? Because if you're using rails 3 [the routes need to use a different style](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/routing.html)